# Node fork child process and get it's errors

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am able to fork a child process, but I am having issues seeing what errors are taking place in that file, and I know the file has errors, because I created an object without a closing `}` so an error should occur. Using the following code, I get nothing (in the console and/or the browser):

```
var child = require('child_process').fork(full_path, [], {
    silent: true,
});

// Tried both of these and nothing gets displayed
child.stdout.on('error', function(data){
    res.write(data);
    console.log(data);
});
child.stderr.on('error', function(data){
    res.write(data);
    console.log(data);
});
```

Here is the child process:

```
var sys = require('sys');
var mustache = require('mustache');
var template = require('./templates/mypage.html');

sys.puts(template);

var view = {
    "musketeers": ["Athos", "Aramis", "Porthos", "D'Artagnan"]
; // Forced error here with no closing "}"

var html = mustache.to_html(template, view);
sys.puts(html);
```

What do I need to do to display the errors? What am I doing incorrectly?

**Edit**

Full script:

```
var sys    = require('sys');
var config = require('./server.json');
var url    = require('url');
var http   = require('http');

function handleRequest(req, res){
    var full_path = "";

    for(var i in config){
        var domain = config[i].server;
        if(req.headers.host === domain){
            var info = url.parse(req.url);
            full_path = config[i].root + info.pathname;
        }
    }

    console.log("Page: " + full_path);

    if(full_path != ""){
        var child = require('child_process').fork(full_path, [], {
            silent: true,
        });
        child.stdout.on('data', function(data){
            res.write(data);
        });
        child.stdout.on('error', function(data){
            res.write(data);
            console.log(data);
        });
        child.stderr.on('error', function(data){
            res.write(data);
            console.log(data);
        });
        child.stdout.on('end', function(){
            res.end();
        });
    }else{
        res.end();
    }
}

var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);
server.listen(3000, function(err){
    console.log(err || 'Server listening on 3000');
});
```

Comment: I tried that too, and it didn't work

Comment: what "didn't work" means? And what did you try?

Comment: it does the same thing, and shows no output, as if it isn't running. Maybe I am using it wrong?

Comment: How did you use it? "Maybe I am using it wrong?" --- I have no idea, I cannot read your mind. Let's wait when fortune tellers come. Or when you post your code.

Comment: 1. What if you listen on `data` not error? 2. Is this a complete scripts? If so - what if the parent exits before the child was forked?

Comment: I have attached a full script

Comment: gonna take a wild guess that `silent: true` is surpressing all output.

Comment: If I comment out `silent: true` the error shows, but crashes the main server.

Comment: Did you ever solve it? I tried this but can't get any errors of child process displayed either. Added `silent:false` to the options passed.

Answer (score 0):

By default all input/output goes back to the parent.

Given `parent.js`

```
var fork = require('child_process').fork;
var child = fork('./child');
```

output and errors from `child.js` go back to parent

```
setInterval(function() {
    console.log('I am here')
}, 1000);
setTimeout(function() {
    throw new Error('oops')
}, 5000);
```

Like @Plato says, `{ silent: true }` is gonna shut things up

Comment: Errors are not being passed between nodes, the child just writes to the parents stderr (when it logs the uncaught exception). The child should be handling it's own errors. If you want to communicate between nodes, look into [messages](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_event_message)